# Changing the frameset row value

Tags: html, frameset, html-frames

I am changing the frameset with this line

```
parent.document.all("Edit").rows="0%,100%,0%";
```

this is the frameset i am changing

```
<frameset id="Edit" border="0" frameborder="0" rows="0%,0%,100%">

  <frame name="PermaPlayer" src="EditPermaPlayer.html?h=<%= System.DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" />
  <frame name="EditPlaylist" src="EditPlaylist.aspx?id=<%= playlistEditingId %>&hs=<%= System.DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" />
  <frame name="EditPlaylistLoading" src="EditPlaylistLoading.aspx?&hsm=<%= System.DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" />
</frameset>
```

Changing it IE works and it works in chrome.  It doesnt work in Firefox.  Is there something diferent that needs to be done in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.all`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537434%28VS.85%29.aspx) is proprietary to Internet Explorer and is absolutely non-standard. Moreover, it's hideously outdated. Use [`document.getElementById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
parent.document.getElementById('Edit').rows = "0%,100%,0%";
```